# PHP check for empty inputs in form (both file and text)

Tags: php, forms, validation, file-upload

Im have some trubbel trying to make a PHP script to check if any text(or someting else) input are empty AND at the same time check if any of the file input are empty.

The code use like some frameworks a $rule where you write the rules for the inputs

**Example:**

```
$rule = array(
    "title" => "required|minLength:5",
    "myFile" => "required"
);
```

I have this function there been looped for each input there are

```
foreach ($rules as $item => $ruleset) {
    // required|email|min:8
    $ruleset = explode('|', $ruleset);

    foreach ($ruleset as $rule) {

        $pos = strpos($rule, ':');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $parameter = substr($rule, $pos + 1);
            $rule = substr($rule, 0, $pos);
        }
        else {
            $parameter = '';
        }

        // Example of this output: validateEmail($item, $value, $param)
        $methodName = 'validate' . ucfirst($rule);
        $value = isset($data[$item]) ? $data[$item] : NULL;

        if (method_exists($this, $methodName)) {
            $this->$methodName($item, $value, $parameter) or $valid = false;
        }
    }
}


// Validate the $value of $item to see if it is present and not empty
private function validateRequired ($item, $value)
{       
    if (empty($value))
    {
        $this->errors[$item][] = 'The ' . $item . ' field is required';
        return false;
    }   
    return true;
}
```

it work, but as we know, a file input need to been check using a $_FILES,

what can I do???

Comment: Not even close to a solution. Way too broad

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear how you're trying to use all those code pieces together, especially the `validateRequired()` function. But given the current scenario, you should add `type` attribute value in `$rules` array as well.

```
$rules = array(
    "title" => "required|minLength:5|type:text",
    "myFile" => "required|type:file"
);
```

And process your form fields based on the `type` of the field. However, I'd suggest you to refactor your business logic using the following `$rules` array,

```
$rules = array(
    'title' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'minLength' => 5,
        'type' => 'text'
    ),
    'myFile' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'type' => 'file'
    )
);
```

With the above `$rules` array, it would be lot easier for you to process your form input fields. So your `foreach` loop would be something like this:

```
foreach($rules as $item => $rule){
    switch($rule['type']){
        case 'text':
            if($rule['required']){
                if(!empty($_POST[$item]) && strlen($_POST[$item]) >= $rule['minLength']){
                    // SUCCESS: The text field complies with required and minLength conditions
                }else{
                    // ERROR: The text field doesn't comply with required and minLength conditions
                }
            }else{
                // Proceed with your logic
            }
            break;
        case 'file':
            if($rule['required']){
                if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$item]['tmp_name'])){
                    // SUCCESS: The file field complies with required condition. User has uploaded a file
                }else{
                    // ERROR: The file field doesn't comply with required condition. User hasn't uploaded any file
                }
            }else{
                // Proceed with your logic
            }
        case 'checkbox':
            // your code


    }
}
```